# How to stop central heating system from leaking

Tags: leak, gas, central-heating, water-circulating-heating

Our central heating system is leaking a bit of water. The system is a Ferolli Megadens 5, it heats water for both the central heating system and the shower/tap.

There are several pipes below the system, and the middle one is (If I read the manual correctly) the gas-pipe. This is one with the yellow covering and the yellow valve . I have a link to the [manual](http://www.ferroli.nl/static/downloadcenter/2011/02/DRS9001_100_montagehandleiding_MegaDens_4-5shr_4.pdf) and while that is dutch-only, I believe the image on page 4 shows it to be number '6', which says "gasleiding" (translated: gas-pipe or 'gas main' as google translates it).

[image: Ferolli megadens 5 bottom pipes]

That middle pipe drips water, and it seems to come from the connection (the bend) as the upper part feels dry, and the connection looks like this up close:

[image]

Bottomline is that it seems to leek water from the gas main, which I think is weird.

It could be condensation of course, but the fact that it is specifically on the connection makes me think it is an actual leak. Not to mention the fact that it has never done that before, and I don't see why it should start condensating all of a sudden .

Rate is not very much, but might be (very rough ballpark) half a cup on some days I guess? In any case it doesn't seem to 'stream', but it does drip actively sometimes (and other times, in fact, most times I look at it, it does nothing and might be almost dry).

This shot was when it was dripping a bit. The heating had been off for 12 hours and no hot water was used in that period as well. The system has an ECO setting that we use, meaning it keeps water at a lower base temperature in those cases, and only starts heating on request. Not sure what that base temp is by the way.

so question is obviously what to do about it, but also should I be worried that there is water there, and/or is there an explanation for it?

Comment: Have you tried cable tying something absorbent, like some kitchen paper between the boiler and that bend to confirm that it really isn't coming down from above?

Comment: I thought I did  (well I did and it was dry), but a second try did show some moisture to my surprise. So it seems like it might be coming from higher up after all. It might be worth it to look inside and see what is going on there I guess.

Comment: It may just be condensing from "something" whether that is a leak in the flue, or something else. I'd always recommend a qualified gas engineer for looking at anything inside the boiler casing (and in some locales it is illegal to work on a gas appliance without suitable qualifications) - it may also help as a professional opinion if you need a warranty swap or similar.

Comment: Sound advice, that was my plan as well, just checking if I was skipping some simple steps first :)